# Weka with Missing Values

Tags: weka, arff

I've a question about weka as this person:

> Hi all:
>
> I felt really strange about WEKA on this.
>
> I have prepared a CSV file which has lots of missing values. One
>   missing value in this file is basic just no any value between pair of
>   commas i.e. ,random_value1,,random_value2. This is an example of the
>   format. You can see there is a pair of commas, between them is just
>   nothing not even a white_space, and it should indicates a missing
>   value of the data.
>
> The weird thing is when I read this CSV into WEKA, WEKA assigns all
>   missing values to a question mark, i.e. '?'. This is exactly how WEKA
>   expresses it.
>
> And then when I run testing analysis, WEKA started working on these
>   '?' as some sort useful information. It just missing values, could
>   WEKA please just jump over it?
>
> These problem became really wasting. Analysis results read like if
>   missing then value missing, missing assocciates with missing, missing
>   correlates missing.
>
> Can WEKA reads missing value as missing value, not some sort question
>   marks? Or can I tell WEKA that for all '?', treat them as missing
>   values?
>
> Thanks guys

He solved his problem using this solution:

I found a way to tell WEKA about the missings. Just use the fine_and_replace function of a ASCII editor, replace all '?' to ?.

>

but I didn't know how can download ASCII Editor and use it ,, can anyone inform me ????

Comment: google for notepad2 or notepad++

Comment: @AtillaOzgur thaaaaaaanks alot ='), write it as answer, to upvote  it =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use  notepad2 or notepad++ in windows.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to work on with missing values. Different algorithms work differently on missing values. So, don't worry, it will be handled just the way it should have been.